# In SwiftUI, how do you filter a list on a subview when passing data through a NavigationLink?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am new to SwiftUI and programming in general. I am trying to pass data and create navigation between different views in my app.

For my data model, I am using MVVM format even though my data is entirely static right now. I have two data models that I am trying to connect via enumeration: CategoryModel and SubCategoryModel (see below).

CategoryModel:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
    
    case explicit = "Explicit"
    case adventure = "Adventure"
    case artists = "Artists"
    case holidays = "Holidays"
    case movies = "Movies"
    case people = "People"
    case tasks = "Tasks"
    case feelings = "Feelings"
    case lifestyle = "Lifesytle"
    case party = "Party"
    case sports = "Sports"
}

//Root data -> set up data structure
//make Identifiable for ForEach looping in other views
struct CategoryModel: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let category: Category
    let categoryTitle: String
    let description: String
    let isPurchase: Bool
    let categoryImage: Image
}

class CategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var gameCategories: [CategoryModel] = CategoryModel.all
    @Published var filteredPurchase: [CategoryModel] = []
    
    init() {
        filterByPurchase()
    }
    
    func filterByPurchase() {
        filteredPurchase = gameCategories.filter({ $0.isPurchase })
    }
}

extension CategoryModel {
    static let all = [
        CategoryModel(
            category: .explicit,
            categoryTitle: "Adults Only",
            description: "For those spicy, intimate moments.",
            isPurchase: true,
            categoryImage: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Explicit"))
        ),
        CategoryModel(
            category: .adventure,
            categoryTitle: "Call of the Wild",
            description: "[Insert description here]",
            isPurchase: false,
            categoryImage: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Adventure"))
        ),
        CategoryModel(
            category: .artists,
            categoryTitle: "By the Artist",
            description: "[Insert description here]",
            isPurchase: false,
            categoryImage: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Artists"))
        ),
    ]
}
```

SubCategoryModel:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

//Root data -> set up data structure
//make Identifiable for ForEach looping in other views
struct SubCategoryModel: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let category: Category
    let subcategory: String
    let subtitle: String
    let subdescription: String
    let instruction: String
    let cardImage: Image
}

class SubCategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var gameSubCategories: [SubCategoryModel] = SubCategoryModel.allSubs
    @Published var filteredCategory: [SubCategoryModel] = []
    @Published var categoryType: Category = .explicit

    init() {
        filterByCategory()
    }
    
    func filterByCategory() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            
            let results = self.gameSubCategories
                .lazy
                .filter { item in
                    return item.category == self.categoryType
                }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.filteredCategory = results.compactMap({ item in
                    return item
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

extension SubCategoryModel {
    static let allSubs = [
        SubCategoryModel(
            category: .explicit,
            subcategory: "Significant Other",
            subtitle: "Bedroom Eyes",
            subdescription: "[Insert sub-description here]",
            instruction: "Instructions:\n \n1) Each player pick a song\n2) Be funny, genuine, or a maverick\n3) Enjoy the trip down memory lane",
            cardImage: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Explicit"))
        ),
        SubCategoryModel(
            category: .explicit,
            subcategory: "Dating",
            subtitle: "First Date",
            subdescription: "[Insert sub-description here]",
            instruction: "Instructions:\n \n1) Each player pick a song\n2) Be funny, genuine, or a maverick\n3) Enjoy the trip down memory lane",
            cardImage: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Explicit"))
        ),
        SubCategoryModel(
            category: .adventure,
            subcategory: "Hiking",
            subtitle: "Bedroom Eyes",
            subdescription: "[Insert sub-description here]",
            instruction: "Instructions:\n \n1) Each player pick a song\n2) Be funny, genuine, or a maverick\n3) Enjoy the trip down memory lane",
            cardImage: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Adventure"))
        ),
    ]
}
```

**My goal** is to click on a card from the CategoryView screen and navigate to the SubCategoryView via a navigation link. I want the SubCategoryView to show a filtered list of subcategories based on the category selected on the CategoryView screen.

[CategoryView to SubCategoryView GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSwNI.gif)

CategoryLoop code snippet:

```
struct CategoryLoop: View {
    
    let categories: [CategoryModel]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150), spacing: 20)], spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(categories) { item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: SubCategoryView()
                                            .navigationTitle(item.category.rawValue)) {
                                CategoryCard(category: item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Based on the code in my CategoryLoop file, what is the best/easiest way to pass my model data and filter the list on the SubCategoryView? I am having trouble figuring out how to use the enumeration. Is it possible to write a function that would update @Published var categoryType: Category = .explicit (see SubCategoryModel) based on the card clicked in the LazyVGrid? Also, if you have suggestion on how to better organise my data models, please let me know.

Comment: The issue that you are having is that your `CategoryModel` doesn't have a  subcategories parameter. If you had a `var subcategories: [SubCategoryModel]` in your `CategoryModel`, your life would be much easier.

Comment: Thanks Yrb! This definitley puts me on the right track. To clarify, when I add `var subcategories: [SubCategoryModel` to the `CategoryModel` I am unsure what to put in the `extension CategoryModel` for `subcategories: ....` for each entry? Once I know this, I assume I can change the reference on my subcategory item views to point to the CategoryModel which will now encompass the subcategory fields as well? Thanks again!

Comment: These are `structs`, not `classes`. They are not reference types. Just put a parameter in your `CategoryModel`. `let subcategories: [SubCategoryModel]`. Then you will access it in your `ForEach` as `item.subcategories`.